# C freeing array and elements fails with double free

Tags: c, arrays, regex, memory-management, memory-leaks

I'm new to C and trying to work with the regex library. So far Ive successfully built an array of regex matches (array of strings) and I'm trying to free the memory used when doing so. Code is here:

```
    #include "basic_curl.h"

//returns an array of strings
//the free_regex_memory should be called when regex results are no longer
//needed
char **regexme(char *_string, const char *reg_to_match, int reg_limit) {

    regex_t preg;
    size_t nmatch = 1;
    regmatch_t pmatch[1];
    int comp_ret;
    int match;
    int start;
    int end = 0;
    int match_len;
    int i;
    int string_offset = 0;

    char **matches = (char **) malloc(sizeof(char *) * reg_limit);

    for (i=0; i < reg_limit; i++) {

    comp_ret = regcomp(&preg, reg_to_match, REG_ICASE|REG_EXTENDED);
    match = regexec(&preg, &_string[string_offset], nmatch, pmatch, 0);

    if (match == 1) {
        puts("No more matches found, rest of the loop will be filled with NULLs");
        break;
    }

    else if (match == 0 ) {
        start = pmatch[0].rm_so;
        end = pmatch[0].rm_eo;

        string_offset += end;
        match_len = end - start;
        printf("%.*s\n", match_len, &_string[string_offset - match_len]);

        //use malloc to find the length and use that instead of limiting array initially
        //http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33003196/cant-copy-string-to-an-array-of-strings-in-c
        matches[i] = malloc(sizeof(char) * (match_len + 1));
        sprintf(matches[i], "%.*s" , match_len, &_string[string_offset - match_len]);

    }
    }

    return matches;
}

int free_regex_memory(char **matches_array) {

    int i = 0;
    while (matches_array[i] != NULL) {
        free(&matches_array[i]);
    }

    //why can't I do this after the above?
    //I get a crash from the below line trying to free the array itself:
    /*
       *** Error in `/home/punk/ClionProjects/curl-ex/src/regmatch': double free or corruption (fasttop): 0x0000000000603010 ***

      Program received signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
      0x00007ffff7a4af79 in __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:56
    */
    free(matches_array);

    return 0;

}

int main() {

    char **matches;
    int i =0;

    matches = regexme("0fff 1fc<a href=\"https://www.blahblahblah.com/whatever.php?xxx=r\" keaw 2eafa", 
              "(http|https)://[%/0-9a-zA-Z\\.\?=&#@:]*",
              10);

    //puts(matches[1]);

    while (matches[i] != NULL) {
        puts(matches[i]);
        i++;
    }

    free_regex_memory(matches);

    return 0;
}
```

Basically the above regexme function extracts regexes from a string and stores them into a dynamically allocated array of strings called "matches"  and returns this from the function. This works well.

My problem is that I'd now like to free the memory associated with the array of strings, which is where the free_regex_memory() function comes in. I loop through the array, and free the memory associated with each element in the matches array and then I try to free the array itself. I can do one or the other, either free the array or free its elements. However trying to do both (as in the code above) gives me the error "double free or corruption" (as seen in comments in code above).

So what gives? All the other SO questions I see mention needing to free the malloced array AND elements to properly free memory, but I can't seem to do so. What am I missing?

As an aside being new to C am I doing anything amazingly dumb or inefficient in this code?

---

Edit: here is my new code based on the comments and answers

```
#include "basic_curl.h"

//returns an array of strings
//the free_regex_memory should be called when regex results are no longer
//needed
char **regexme(char *_string, const char *reg_to_match, int reg_limit) {

    regex_t preg;
    size_t nmatch = 1;
    regmatch_t pmatch[1];
    int comp_ret;
    int match;
    int start;
    int end = 0;
    int match_len;
    int i;
    int string_offset = 0;

    //char **matches = (char **) malloc(sizeof(char *) * reg_limit);

    void **matches = malloc(sizeof(char *) * reg_limit);

    for (i=0; i < reg_limit; i++) {

    comp_ret = regcomp(&preg, reg_to_match, REG_ICASE|REG_EXTENDED);
    match = regexec(&preg, &_string[string_offset], nmatch, pmatch, 0);

    if (match == 1) {
        puts("No more matches found, rest of the loop will be filled with NULLs");
        break;
    }

    else if (match == 0 ) {
        start = pmatch[0].rm_so;
        end = pmatch[0].rm_eo;

        string_offset += end;
        match_len = end - start;
        printf("%.*s\n", match_len, &_string[string_offset - match_len]);

        //use malloc to find the length and use that instead of limiting array initially
        //http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33003196/cant-copy-string-to-an-array-of-strings-in-c
        matches[i] = malloc(sizeof(char) * (match_len + 1));
        sprintf(matches[i], "%.*s" , match_len, &_string[string_offset - match_len]);

    }
    }

    return matches;
}

int free_regex_memory(char **matches_array) {

    int i = 0;
    //fixed so that i'm no longer dereferencing the array element addresses and incrementing the pointer
    while (matches_array[i] != NULL) {
        free(matches_array[i]);
         i++;
    }

    //this works now
    free(matches_array);

    return 0;

}

int main() {

    char **matches;
    int i =0;

    matches = regexme("0fff 1fc<a href=\"https://www.blahblahblah.com/whatever.php?xxx=r\" keaw 2eafa", 
              "(http|https)://[%/0-9a-zA-Z\\.\?=&#@:]*",
              10);

    //puts(matches[1]);

    while (matches[i] != NULL) {
        puts(matches[i]);
        i++;
    }

    free_regex_memory(matches);

    return 0;
}
```

---

Oh and here is basic_curl.h in case anyone wants to compile this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>
#include <regex.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

struct MemWriteData {

    size_t size;
    char *memory;
};

static size_t write_callback(char *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *userp);
char **regexme(char *_string, const char *reg_to_match, int reg_limit);
int free_regex_memory(char **matches_array);
```

Comment: Shouldn't `free(&matches_array[i]);` be `free(matches_array[i]);`?  When you do it with `i == 0`, you are doing what you then try with `free(matches_array)` — a double free as identified by the library.

Comment: I thought the same thing, however looking at it in GDB matches_array[0] and matches_array are two distinct memory addresses:

`(gdb) x/s matches[0]
0x603ae0: "https://www.blahblahblah.com/whatever.php?xxx=r"
(gdb) x/s matches
0x603010: "\340:`"`

Comment: 1) General rule: do not cast unless you really know what you do (as you sometimes cast, sametimes not, shows you do not). 2) Do not cast the result of `malloc` & friends in C. You do not have an array, but a pointer to pointer. 4) A pointer is not an array.

Comment: @Olaf absolutely I don't know what I'm doing. That's why I said I was new in C :). In what situations should or should I not cast? Should it, in general then be something like `void **matches = malloc(sizeof(char *) * reg_limit);`? I mostly understand difference btwn pointers and arrays, but they are highly related if i understand correctly. I return a pointer to pointers because I want to reference an array or pointers and one cannot return arrays in C. Is any of this incorrect?

Comment: Agreed that `matches_array[0]` and `matches_array` are two different addresses, but that's irrelevant since you're passing `&matches_array[0]` and `matches_array` to `free()`, and those are the same address.  You really don't want the `&` in the call to `free`.   I have to disagree with the accepted answer, though I confess I've not formally compiled and run the code (in part, because I don't have `basic_curl.h` to make it compilable).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler ah I see, yeah I didn't want the &, the accepted answer showed me that :). I understand now, the & was in fact giving me the same address as just matches_array, thus the error. It seems to me like you're saying the same thing as the accepted answer though but I may be misunderstanding something. I'm editing now with the new code based on comments and answer

Comment: Oh; I see – the accepted answer is pointing what's wrong, rather than showing what's right.  Then I agree with it.

Comment: @acnutch note that in C you should *always* check your return values. It seems that you do not in your code, however. In particular, calls to `malloc()` may fail by returning `NULL`. If that occurs and you continue to use the returned `NULL` pointer you may find *undefined behavior* including anything from it "working" to "weird errors" to it simply crashing (at *any point*). I highly suggest you put some thought into some minimal error handling. I'm less familiar with the curl API but I imagine you're not handling its possible errors either.

Comment: @inetknght - If malloc() fails, it's doubtful there is enough resources left, leaving a locked machine.

Comment: Imagine all the deep nested calls you'd have to unwind if _malloc()_ fails. Luckily, if the allocation can be paged, it will likely never fail unless it is extreme.

Comment: @sin nonsense. I've encountered legitimate `malloc()` failures from insufficient resources on production environments and *not* had a locked machine and successfully handled the situation. Yes, there *can be* "a lot" of nested calls to unwind. On the flip side there might not be. The best thing to do depends on what situation you're in and how you want to handle the failure. Do you wait some time, retry later, up to some number of times? Do you go straight to reporting the error? Either way is better than a crash -- or worse, undefined behavior -- as far as most users are concerned!

Comment: @inetknght - I stopped checking the return for _error_ years and years ago. The most I do now is declare the pointer null, any place I use it is wrapped in `if ( pointer ) {  }` then don't ever worry about it. Never have I seen the heap overflow on paged memory systems. Never tried to do it either. It's not a behavior that is usually a concern of the user, only for production debugging.

Comment: @sln: Relying on undefined behaviour is certainly nothing one should be proud of. And recommending this to a beginner in a programming forum is definitively contraproductive. Something like "I have not ..." does not mean there is no problem. Who knows what problems your code has produced, how much money it costed and who you even might have killed.

Comment: @Olaf - Who are you the C policeman ? I produce and sell my own. `behaviour is undefined` yeah, I've never seen that before.

Comment: I'm an embedded systems engineer who also works on safety-critical systems. Writing such code you decribe would be a good way to get instantly fired in this area. But for consumer-TVs ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have:

> ```
> int i = 0;
> while (matches_array[i] != NULL) {
>     free(&matches_array[i]);
> }
> ```

- you're freeing the address of `matches_array[i]`. I don't believe that's intended.
- you're never incrementing `i`

You need code equivalent to this (using a `for` loop is an option):

```
int i = 0;
while (matches_array[i] != NULL) {
    free(matches_array[i++]);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, absolutely correct on both. That fixes the issue. I'll go punch myself in the face now.

Comment: Ok, now I understand you just cite the code of OP. Colud you please better mark that as a citation? I took this for you correction. maybe you should add the correct code:`free(matches_array[i])` to make your intention more clear.

Comment: How do you mark it as a citation? *update* I believe I fixed it for you

Answer (score 1):

More advice -

From Wikipedia:

> The memory set aside by malloc is not initialized and may contain cruft: the remnants of previously used and discarded data

When using *malloc()*, clear the memory block after allocating it:

```
char **matches = (char **) malloc(sizeof(char *) * reg_limit);
memset( (char *)matches, 0, sizeof(char *) * reg_limit );
```

Don't depend on a hard end to *matches_array* pointers, use the limit you've allocated:

```
void free_regex_memory( char **matches_array, int reg_limit )
{
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < reg_limit; i++)
    {
        if ( matches_array[i] != NULL )
           free( matches_array[i] );   // initial problem
    }
    free(matches_array);
}
```

Called from *Main*:

```
int main()
{
    char **matches;
    int i =0;

    /////////////////

    free_regex_memory( matches, reg_limit );
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do not cast `void *` in C.

Comment: Where do you see `void *`